# Plot each row of data across all columns (Spaghetti plot)

Tags: r, plot, transpose

I have a [**small dataset**](https://github.com/izeh/i/blob/master/De.csv) consisting of 16 rows and 5 columns. This dataset is shown below the picture, and can also be imported to R using:

```
  d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/De.csv")[-1]
```

**Goal:** My goal is to plot each row of data across all columns (**Spaghetti plot**) in base R. For example, for 3 rows (out of total 16 rows), I expect something like the ***picture below.***

**Question:** I tried `matplot()` with no success, is there a **BASE R** solution?

```
matplot(d)
```

[image]

**The entire data:**

```
   GolBkgnd DesnTst Result PrdctConc PostBrd
1         4       4      3         5       5
2         2       3      5         3       5
3         5       4      3         5       4
4         3       4      4         1       3
5         5       3      2         4       4
6         5       4      5         5       4
7         5       3      3         1       5
8         5       4      5         5       4
9         5       3      2         1       3
10        5       4      3         4       5
11        5       3      1         4       3
12        3       4      3         4       5
13        5       3      4         2       5
14        4       4      3         5       5
15        5       3      3         5       4
16        5       4      4         3       5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With base R, seems like you just need to transpose with `t()` and draw the axis yourself

```
matplot(t(d), type="l", xaxt="n")
axis(1, seq_along(d), names(d))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Just many are on top of each other. You can add some noise to see it with `matplot(t(d)+rnorm(nrow(d)*ncol(d)), type="l", xaxt="n")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  mutate(index = 1:16) %>%
  gather(column, value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(column, value, color = index, group = index)) + 
  geom_lines()
```

Comment: Melissa, thank you for your input. I'm looking for a Base R solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are diagramming what's know as "parallel coordinates plot". The fact that the lines all end up overlapping each other leads me to suggest using jitter to slightly separate them at random:

```
library(MASS)
png()
parcoord( sapply(d, jitter))
dev.off()
```

[image]

The MASS package is arguably a "base"-R package. If you need to identify by colors, then":

```
parcoord( sapply(d, jitter), col=1:16)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not criticizing the matplot solution, which is the one you accepted? The default for its colors is to use 8 colors.

Comment: If I look at the output of colors()[1:16] I see why you are dissatisfied. You could try a larger interval between colors with `col=colors()[round(200 / 8*(1:16))]` or you could read and follow the links on `?palette`